# Select rows greater than the last maximum in the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

The problem I'm dealing with involves a drilling database. The table has two columns, the first with the depth recorded by a sensor and the second with a timestamp. During the drilling, the equipment might be returned back up in order to have its bit changed.

[image: An example of the table follows:]

I'm trying to make a query that would describe how long it takes to drill each meter (0-1; 1-2; 2-3), for example:

[image: Duration of each meter drilled]

The problem I'm facing is that when making this comparison between rows in SQL Server, if I try comparing `max(Timestamp)` after grouping I end up including the data from when the bits return, which I don't want to do.

```
Select
Case when a.depth > 0 and a.depth <= 1 then '0-1'
when depth > 1 and depth <= 2 then '1-2' -- and so on until 10m where it ends… 
end as 'Class',
(max(Timestamp) - min(Timestamp)) as 'Duration'
from Table
group by Class
order by Class
```

Does anyone know how to make this comparison between rows of the same column? Basically, it needs to ignore any values that are lower than its last maximum.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is quite nice for a first post. The problem is clearly communicated, the title describes the general problem instead of your business logic, and you’ve appropriately included the code you’re working from. Nice job.

Comment: could you show how you arrived at 02:00 for the drill group 4-5

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, the second table came out weird, I've made it in excel with what I remembered from the problem.  Normally, the depth records would be gradual, and we would have values for all classes of depth.

Comment: Your desired output shows a value for <4-5> but you seem to have skipped <5-6>. Why? At depth 5 there was bit change, correct? So you want to ignore anything after that depth until depth 5 is reached again? Or just ignore anything between depth 5 and the next "boundary"? And you may have a much larger issue yet to be faced when your time values cross midnight.

Comment: As I said, I've made table  2 came out a bit weird, I'll update it when I'm home. On a real scenario, there will be values for all boundaries (1-2; 2-3; 3-4 ....). As for the time issue, it won't be a problem as this drilling only happens during daylight. The desire is to ignore any rows that have a lower value than the last maximum value registered by the sensor.